# Delayed Job Delayed::PerformableMethod undefined method "delayed_task" for #<Class:0x0000000b4dcd20>

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I am using delayed jobs and I think I have a problem with serialization. We are using ruby 2.2.2.

In my model I have a callback that fires on save and creates a delayed job for my model. like this:

```
after_create :update_queue

def update_queue
  self.class.delay(run_at: 1.minutes.from_now, delayed_reference_id: self.id, delayed_reference_type: "Payment", queue: "qbo_payments").delayed_task(self.id)
end

def self.delayed_task
  # Do some stuff
end
```

However I am getting the error:

```
undefined method `delayed_task' for #<Class:0x0000000f93f9b8>
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted.rb:295:in `method_missing'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:129:in `method_missing_with_attr_encrypted'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:26:in `perform'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:84:in `block in invoke_job'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:81:in `invoke_job'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.16.0.318/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/delayed_job_instrumentation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_job'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.16.0.318/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:363:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.16.0.318/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/delayed_job_instrumentation.rb:126:in `invoke_job'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:230:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:89:in `block in timeout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:230:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:229:in `run'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:306:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:306:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:213:in `block in work_off'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `times'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `work_off'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:175:in `block (4 levels) in start'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:174:in `block (3 levels) in start'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:173:in `block (2 levels) in start'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `loop'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `block in start'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:171:in `start'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:132:in `run'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:120:in `block in run_process'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:265:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:265:in `block in start_proc'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:84:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:84:in `call_as_daemon'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:269:in `start_proc'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:295:in `start'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/controller.rb:69:in `run'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons.rb:193:in `block in run_proc'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `call'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `catch_exceptions'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons.rb:192:in `run_proc'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:118:in `run_process'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:99:in `block in daemonize'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:97:in `times'
~/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:97:in `daemonize'
script/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'"
```

**What I have tried**

After a bit of google research I found 2 fixes. The first and more widely accepted fix is to add:

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
#https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/199
```

However, syck is no longer supported for ruby 2.2.2

The second solution, which only seemed to exacerbate the problem, was to add "bundle exec" to my delayed_job startup script like this:

```
run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec script/delayed_job start #{rails_env}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work !

```
after_create :update_queue

def update_queue
 self.delay(run_at: 1.minutes.from_now, delayed_reference_id: self.id, delayed_reference_type: "Payment", queue: "qbo_payments").delayed_task()
end

def delayed_task
   self.class.delayed_task(self.id)
end

def self.delayed_task
 # Do some stuff
end
```